# Error al compilar: "This relative module was not found:" en proyecto vue con apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql

tengo un problema con el archivo `main.js` de apollo con vue, y al intentar correr la aplicación con `npm run serve` me da el siguiente fallo de compilación: 
`This relative modile was not found: ./vue-apollo in ./src/main.js`

Os dejo el código del archivo `main.js`. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { createProvider } from './vue-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import VueApollo, { ApolloProvider } from 'vue-apollo';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  url: 'https://movie-database-graphql.herokuapp.com/graphiql'
});

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
});

Vue.use(VueApollo);

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  apolloProvider,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Dos cosas el `createProvider` no esta siendo usado. Y segundo ¿tienes el export del `createProvider `? o mejor puedes publicar el contenido de tu archivo  `vue-apollo`

Comment: El problema es que el archivo vue-apollo no se me ha creado al instalar apollo